# .xsession-errors huge file

Tags: 11.04

My ~/.xsession-errors file is growing quickly.  The following error is repeated over and over:

(nautilus:1595): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_value_get_object: assertion `G_VALUE_HOLDS_OBJECT (value)' failed

Comment: Can you (for others' benefit) specify what you *want* accomplished? Do you want that error not to occur? Do you want the logfile to be smaller through autoemptying? Something else?

Comment: Ideally I would like the error not to occur.  I would also be happy if the logfile was smaller through autoemptying.

Comment: Consider `log-rotate`, following by deleting the rotated-out logs. I have little experience with `log-rotate`, so maybe somebody could elaborate on my idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented bug that has been fixed in 12.04. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdbusmenu/+bug/870742

Comment: I am not running 12.04, I am running 11.04

Comment: I added the following lines to my logrotate.conf file:

/home/andrew/.xsession-errors {
        size 1k
        rotate 0
        
}

I then copied /etc/cron.daily/logrotate to /etc/cron.hourly/logrotate

I believe this will clear my .xsession-errors file every hour if it is larger than 1k.

Comment: I understand that you are on 11.04. My point was that it is a known issue that cannot be fixed. Therefore, your only options are workarounds (like what you've already implemented) or upgrading to 12.04.

Comment: @bock, Tom: Or a [stable release update](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) could be requested. Can you edit your answer to include a link to the bug report showing Fix Released for Precise?